# Web service method List<Object> parameter

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, maximo

I want to be able to receive a list of Injured objects in my web service method. Below is the java bean created for the object:

```
public class Injured implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String age;
    private String status;
    private String injurytype;
    private String death;
    private String gender;
    private String nationality;
    private String injuredtype;
    private String file;
    private String rank;

    public Injured ()
    {
    }

    //Getters
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
    public String getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return this.status;
    }
    public String getInjuryType()
    {
        return this.injurytype;
    }
    public String getDeath()
    {
        return this.death;
    }
    public String getGender()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }
    public String getNationality()
    {
        return this.nationality;
    }
    public String getInjuredType()
    {
        return this.injuredtype;
    }
    public String getFile()
    {
        return this.file;
    }
    public String getRank()
    {
        return this.rank;
    }

    //Setters

    public setName (String s)
    {
        this.name = s;
    }
    public setNumber (String s)
    {
        this.number = s;
    }
    public setAge (String s)
    {
        this.age = s;
    }
    public setStatus (String s)
    {
        this.status = s;
    }
    public setInjuryType (String s)
    {
        this.injurytype = s;
    }
    public setDeath (String s)
    {
        this.death = s;
    }
    public setGender (String s)
    {
        this.gender = s;
    }
    public setNationality (String s)
    {
        this.nationality = s;
    }
    public setInjuredType (String s)
    {
        this.injuredtype = s;
    }
    public setFile (String s)
    {
        this.file = s;
    }
    public setRank (String s)
    {
        this.rank = s;
    }
}
```

Then in my web service class I'm just replacing a set of String parameters (the fields used in the java bean) with a List. However, when I compile the new web service class and re-generate the XSD file it doesn't show the new parameter but it removed the replaced String parameters. Is there an annotation I'm missing somewhere? Because it seems it's not recognizing it.
The WSDL and XSD files are generated by the enterprise application if that helps clear things.

Comment: How can you replace a string field with a List? It would not even compile. Please place your code here (and you can strip off the getters/setters methods to save the space).

Comment: @Zielu I just meant that in my web service method I replaced the String parameters I needed with one List<Injured>.

E.g. createIncident(String name, String age, String num etc....)
Became createIncident(List<Injured> injureds)